# Mistake in Online Passport Application

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, passport-renewals

I'm applying for a new British passport and have submitted and payed on the online application but haven't yet send the declaration form.

I noticed my mobile phone number I supplied is missing the first unit. What is the correct procedure to resolve this mistake?

Comment: Why not just call the passport office?

Comment: Agreed, call the passport office and let them know the mistake, hopefully they'll be able to guide you step by step on how to correct this mistake.

Comment: I am confident that your mobile number doesn't go on your UK passport; I believe it is only there for them to contact you should they have any queries on your application (which is unlikely to happen). So it's not really critical, and I wouldn't worry - they probably won't even notice it.

Answer (score 3):

It's an honest mistake they likely encounter daily so you should have no issues ringing/emailing to explain it.

If it's just a leading zero it may not even be an issue?

Regardless, I don't see much opportunity to mitigate the possibility of extra fees paid if they decide to make you resubmit.

The earlier you contact them the less likely it is that any processing will have occurred - no promises, but this *may* work out in your favour ...

[image]